# Is there a non-constructive proof-functional logic

Tags: logic, constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic

I understand that classical logic preserves truth, is bivalent, and contains non-constructive proofs. In contrast, intuitionistic logic preserves justification/verification for a proof, is not bivalent, and contains only constructive proofs.

Is there an example of a logic that preserves justification/verification, but is neither constructive nor bivalent? Is there something about a logic that preserves proof that requires it to be constructive?

Comment: Is a logic having at least one nonconstructive proof considered to be not constructive?

Comment: Do you have precise definitions for "constructive" and "preserves proof"?

Comment: @coffeemath yes, I’d say so.

Comment: Intuitionistic predicate logic plus an axiom saying there are two different not further specified things, $\exists x. \exists y. x\neq y$?

Comment: @Karl a constructive proof of a formula $\mathcal A$ demonstrates that $\mathcal A$ is the case without using proof by contradiction or something equivalent. As a consequence, no disjunction can be proven constructively unless one of the disjuncts is provable, and the same thing for existence.

Comment: @Nikolaj-K aren’t existential statements only constructively valid if there is an explicit witness for it?

Comment: @RW_123 Well you're asking for a non-construction framework, so whatever the interpretation of your question shall be, it won't be the case that everything about it is constructive. The word is a bit broad, given there's are so called constructive schools of arithmetic theory which are disproving each other's principles and theorems. To distinguish "constructive" and "proof preserving", we might have to go beyond natural deduction. I tried interpreting the question, making up something which lacks constructive justification but is hard to invoke as anything but a premise (i.e. not a scheme).

Answer (score 3):

There is a logic that is neither bivalent nor constructive: Lukasiewiz 3-valued logic.  The chief reason it is not more widely employed appears to be that in the usual and original form, it is not truth-preserving. Neither modus ponens nor the transitive law of the conditional hold, which make deduction difficult, to say the least.

What is not generally recognized is that they should not. Lukasiewicz logic allows doubtful conditionals. If modus ponens held, it would be possible to combine a doubtful premise and a doubtful conditional to yield a false conclusion. Likewise, if the transitive law held, it would be possible to chain two doubful conditionals to start from a true premise and reach a false conclusion.

It is also not generally recognized that it is possible to easily define a strict conditional that *is* truth preserving. I note that this is not the same as the strict conditional employed in the Lewis systems of modal logic.

Comment: "Neither modus ponens nor the transitive law of the conditional hold"  Why do you say this?  Are you regarding the third truth value as "true"?  Lukasiewicz's axiomatization of that logic does have modus ponens, and the transitive law of the conditoinal is a deducible rule of inference.  For all truth values of 'p' and 'q' in Lukasiwieicz, if 'p' is true, and if 'Cpq' is true, 'q' is true.  Do you reject that as 'modus ponens'?

What doesn't hold though is the distributive law of the conditional, and the deduction meta-thoerem.

Comment: @ Doug Spoonwood I take the third value as 'u'. I understand modus ponens as 'CKpCpqq', which evaluates as 't' in all cases except where  p has a value of 'u' and q has a value of 'f'. I take the transitive law of the conditional to be CKCpqCqrCpr, which  has a value of 'u' in the case where p has a value of 't', q has a value of 'u, and r has a value of 'f'. This was observed by Lewis & Langford .  What they failed to observe is that "LCKpLCpq" has a value of 't' in all cases, and so does LCKLCpqLCqrLCpr.

Comment: Lewis and Langford, (1932), And that next to last is LCKpLCpqq.

Comment: Ah, I see.  By 'modus ponens' I thought you meant the rule of inference {Cpq, p} $\vdash$ q, and by transitive law, I thought you meant either the rule of inference {Cpq, Cqr} $\vdash$ Cpr or the formula CCpqCCqrCpr.

Comment: Forbidding or restricting doubtful conditionals by using LCpq instead of Cpq as the proper 3-valued analogue of the material conditional has some amazing effects.